# Index on Spatial / DBGeography Property for Entity Framework Code First

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, spatial

I have an EF (6.1) code first project and one of its model has a DbGeography Property (which will contain only POINT geographies) which I'll perform queries against.

I declare custom indices following [the official guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#PropertyIndex), however it is lacking details regarding indices for spatial members / properties and I was wondering how I can create those via Code First?

The underlying Database is / will be SQL Server 2012 if that plays any role.

Answer (score 2):

Could not comment.

Practically same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24750207/4977243).

Apparently it cannot be done.

Comment: Can the down-voter please tell me why? Otherwise I will not be able to avoid the same pitfall in the future. I merely wanted to provide a link where practically the same question was answered and the answer accepted and I did not have enough rep to just add it as a comment.